# Free/Paid Alternative to Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

Moodle is quite obsolote right now and in my opinion, it does not solve a problem. Also, it's not a very elegant solution. But my company is very protective about Moodle since they always used it, so i'm looking for a free or paid alternative to Moodle. Something similar, but please, more modern. Thanks!

Comment: this is not programming related, best suited on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a *programming* Q&A site, not a site for shopping recommendations. (also, Moodle is outdated? How? Not enough AJAX and rounded borders?)

Comment: Your question would be better if you provide a specific need that it doesn't meet, which we could then help you with. Assuming you mean it doesn't look nice (we all know this BTW ;), bear in mind that it has far more theming flexibility than most other LMS solutions. You may need a good themer to make it more elegant, rather than a replacement system which will remove all your institutional knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BlackBoard](http://www.blackboard.com/) is a common alternative, but I don't know how "modern" it is.  I've used it in some classes, and Moodle in others.

In my experience, BlackBoard has more features, but it looks like it's designed to support old Internet Explorer like browsers.  There's no AJAX or CSS3 that I've seen.

Comment: Luck has it that I went to a presentation today and they spent about 25 minutes talking about the new version of blackboard.  It's much nicer than the old one, and it has the bells, whistles, and polish you might be looking for.  HTH